# is there way to use realtime event handling like pusher for local network?

Tags: laravel, socket.io, vuejs2, pusher, pusher-js

I'm working on a project for an organization which has a local network and the servers don't have access to the internet. I new to Vue and real-time events. So is there a way to use services like pusher or socket.io offline?
there is this package "tristandunn/pusher-fake" does this do the job or not?
Thanks alot

Comment: socket.io yeah, as its not a 3rd party service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is. You can easliy host your own socket.io server. [tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server) is a great example of this.

Since a few months, there is also a php-based Laravel package to handle websockets: https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets

Comment: I recommend using `beyondcode/laravel-websockets` as it does not introduce another technology (nodejs) in the project. Works like a charm.